# IonViewDidLoad doesnot load the data from service class in Ionic after building the apk file

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I built a form where user can fill all the information about him including the country code which will be provided through the dropdowns, and the data will be displayed after submitting the button. Everything is working fine when I run it on browser. But when I build the apk file, the country codes does not gets loaded. I have kept the JSON file of countries code in assets and is getting it through the providers. Then I am calling the service in the IonViewDidLoad, like this,

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.service.getData()
    .subscribe(
      (success: Country) => {
        this.country = success;
        console.log(success);
      },
      err => {
        this.toast.create({
          message: JSON.parse(err)
        }).present()
      }
    )
  }
```

My service class

```
private url = "../../assets/imgs/country.json";
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello AppointmentProvider Provider');
  }

  public getData(){
    return this.http.get<any>(this.url);
  }
```

I also tried to call the service class from the IonViewDidEnter and also from the constructor, but wasn't successfull here also.

Please help me as I am new to Ionic and angular

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since we do not have more info about the project, I'd suggest you to use angular lifecycle events and report back if there is a change in behavior.

To be exact, could you run with this code:

`ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.service.getData()
    .subscribe(
      (success: Country) => {
        this.country = success;
        console.log(success);
      },
      err => {
        this.toast.create({
          message: JSON.parse(err)
        }).present()
      }
    )
  }`